# How to fix "Invalid argument" of pexpect send/sendline on windows with python?

Tags: python, windows, pexpect

On windows 10 I am using the following python code to send a command to a device

```
import pexpect
from pexpect import popen_spawn
session = popen_spawn.PopenSpawn(f"plink.exe -ssh 192.168.200.10 9000")
session.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=2)
session.send("$SYS,INFO\r\n")
time.sleep(5)
print(session.read_nonblocking(4096, 1))
```

But all I get is an error

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I tried to encode the string, use `sendline` instead, with and without the `\r\n`, but always the same error. Anything I am missing here?

- windows 10
- python 3.10.11
- pexpect 4.8.0

Comment: why do u still `send()` after `expect(EOF)`?

Comment: Because I want to send something?

Comment: @pynexj removing this line does  not change the outcome

Comment: `pydoc pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn` says
*This should not be instantiated directly: use :class:`pexpect.spawn` or
  :class:`pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn`*.

Comment: @meuh Documentation is great, but reality is even greater! And reality says: `AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'`

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was reading the Unix version of the doc. I see from
an earlier post you used pexpect to "plink.exe -ssh" with no problems.
Isn't there a "plink.exe -telnet" you can try?

Comment: @meuh Yes could be, I have so extreme trouble using telnet I lost track of all the issues and questions. Using the `plink.exe` I might have been able to send something to the device, but I cannot read stuff. I now get a `FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused` error. See updated question. But when I manually telnet top that device it works just fine...